# Subclassing native objects

Tags: javascript, oop, subclass

I want to create my own RegExp subclass, with additional methods. This is the most simplified version of my approach:

```
// Declare the subclass
function subRegExp(){}

// Inherit from the parent class
subRegExp.prototype = new RegExp();

// Create a new instance
regex = new subRegExp('[a-z]', 'g');
```

But i am unable to create a new instance.

[This](http://perfectionkills.com/how-ecmascript-5-still-does-not-allow-to-subclass-an-array/) tells me ECMAScript doesn't support subclassing of native objects, but it's been 5 years, so I am hoping there are some options now.

How can I achieve this?

EDIT: Is this ok or will I run into some problems?

```
function subRegExp(str, flags){

    var instance = new RegExp(str, flags);

    // Custom method
    instance.setFlags = function(flags){
        return new subRegExp(this.source, flags);
    }

    return instance;
}

regex = new subRegExp('[a-z]', 'g');
```

Answer (score 2):

Wrappers are your friend, and a common solution to providing extended functionality without using inheritance.

```
var MyRegexClass = function(regExpInstance) { 
  this.originalRegex = regExpInstance;
};

// Replicate some of the native RegExp methods in your wrapper if you need them.
MyRegexClass.prototype.test = function(str) {
    return this.originalRegex.test(str);
};

MyRegexClass.prototype.exec = function (str) {
    return this.originalRegex.exec(str);
};

// Now add in your own methods.
MyRegexClass.prototype.myCustomFunction0 = function () { 
    // this method does something with this.originalRegex
};
MyRegexClass.prototype.myCustomFunction1 = function () {
    // this method also does something with this.originalRegex
};

// Example usage
var matchDavids = new MyRegexClass(/David/);

// this call works, because my class provides the .test() method.
var hasMatch = matchDavids.test('David walked his dog to the park.');

// this call does not work, because my class does not expose the .compile() method.
matchDavids.compile();
// I would need to provide a .compile() method on MyRegexClass that calls to
// the originalRegex.compile().
```

Yes, you lose the inheritance chain.  `MyRegexClass` does not inherit from the native RegExp.  In my experience, wrappers are easier to test and maintain than inheritance-based extensions.

Answer (score 1):

## I'm afraid it still doesn't.

However, you may be able to simulate some of the required functionality by using a custom wrapper object class. Use encapsulation in the constructor to give it a RegExp object as (the closest thing Javascript has to) a private field.

Comment: I've edited my question with your idea, did I miss something?

Comment: You'd have to omit the `new` keyword if you do it that way.

Comment: @notyourtype With your new code you're not actually creating a subclass. `regex instanceof subRegExp` will be `false`. You're just creating an alternate constructor instead. (The fact that you're calling it with `new` is essentially irrelevant if it returns an Object other than `this`.)

Answer (score 1):

I tried this:

```
// Declare the subclass
function subRegExp(){}
// make your object inherit from regex object
subRegExp.prototype = Object.create( RegExp.prototype );

var x = new subRegExp();
// see if your custom object inherited the RegExp properties/functions/methods
console.dir( "compile" in x );
console.dir( x.compile );
```

Output:

```
true
function compile() { [native code] }
```

Comment: Yeah, but calling a native constructor on the new object would likely not work.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is now possible in ES6:

```
class R extends RegExp {}
var r = new R("baz", "g");
return r.exec("foobarbaz")[0] === "baz" && r.lastIndex === 9;
```

We have a test for it in ES6 compat table where you could see [which implementations support it](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#test-RegExp_is_subclassable_RegExp.prototype.exec).

I'll try to update my blog post (that you referenced) about [Array subclassing in ES5](http://perfectionkills.com/how-ecmascript-5-still-does-not-allow-to-subclass-an-array/) sometime soon.